# Similar transformation matrix with minimum norm

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces

Suppose $A$ is a diagonalizable matrix, then we can find an invertible matrix $T$ such that $A=TDT^{-1}$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with entries be the eigenvalues of $A$. For simplicity, we can assume $A$ is non-negative with entries bounded above by $c$. My question is how to find the $T$ such that $\|T\|\|T^{-1}\|$ is minimized, and is it possible to give an upper bound of the minimum value? Here $\|\cdot\|$ is some matrix norm, say the induced $l_2$-norm?

I know each column of $T$ is an eigenvector of $A$, but I have no idea what to do next.

Comment: If the eigenvalues are distinct, then $T$ is unique up to a diagonal scaling since each eigenspace is of dimension $1$. The problem thus reduces to finding the the best diagonal preconditioned of $T$

Comment: @eepperly16 Yes.